# Applescript are there more default icons defined besides stop, caution, note for dialogs and such?

Tags: applescript

When setting icons, for instance for dialogs, I would prefer to reuse the default system icons, instead of loading a custom `.icns` file.

In applescript however I've only found constants defined for 3 icons: Stop, Caution and Note.

The Standard Additions dictionary seems to confirm this:

[image: pictore of display dialog definition]

Are there any other constants defined?

Comment: here's another article that seems to indicate the same: https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/mac-os-x/applescript-customizing-dialog-boxes

Answer (score 1):

No. AppleScript dictionaries are static.

You can use one of the three `with icon` ways:

- An integer representation of the three icons `stop` / `note` / `caution` (0, 1, 2)
- An icon constant `stop` / `note` / `caution`
- A custom icon (`alias` specifier preferred)